# Анимация Opacity для DropShadowEffect

Tags: c#, wpf

В XAML-коде имеется такой элемент `border` с `DropShadowEffect`:

```
<Border BorderBrush="#FF8908" BorderThickness="0,3,0,0" Background="#2C7692" >

                <Border.Effect >
                    <DropShadowEffect x:Name="b_shadow" ShadowDepth="5"
                          Color="#FFFFA23B"
                          Direction="90"
                          BlurRadius="8" RenderingBias="Quality"/>
                </Border.Effect>

                <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="field" Padding="3,0,0,2"  DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="#2C7692" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"  FontFamily="Phenomena" Foreground="#FFA646" Text="0"></TextBlock>
                </Viewbox>
</Border>
```

Программно создаю анимацию `Opacity` для `DropShadowEffect`:

```
var animation = new DoubleAnimation();
animation.From = b_shadow.Opacity;
animation.To = 0;
animation.AutoReverse = true;
animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800);
animation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
b_shadow.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, animation);
```

По идее, во время работы приложения у `DropShadowEffect` должен быть эффект плавного возникновения и исчезновения (пульсации). Однако такого эффекта не наблюдается. Что я упустил?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте для этого Storyboard, через код либо через XAML разметку.

### С#

- Сама анимация тут сильно не изменится:

  ```
  var animation = new DoubleAnimation
  {
      To = 0,
      AutoReverse = true,
      Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800),
      RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
  };
  ```
- Далее мы указываем цель анимации. Целью будет сам Border, а не его эффект (переносим `x:Name` на сам Border) Второй строкой указывается к чему именно будет применен эффект:

  ```
  Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, borderOne);
  Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("Effect.Opacity"));
  ```
- Ну а дальше остается добавить анимацию на TimeLine и запустить:

  ```
  var storyboard = new Storyboard {Children = new TimelineCollection {animation}};
  storyboard.Begin();
  ```

### XAML

Через разметку XAML тоже довольно просто добавлять анимацию, все тоже самое. Нам нужно всего лишь указать внутри Border'a примерно такой код:

```
<Border.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Effect.Opacity" Duration="0:0:0.800" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Border.Triggers>
```

Вот собственно и все, ваша пульсация должна заработать ;-)

Comment: Благодарю) Но все же, почему мой способ не работает? Чисто спортивный интерес)

Comment: @Moonlight Если я не ошибаюсь, то анимация применяется на контролы и их свойства, но не на эффекты.